# api request connection issue in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, node.js-got

I'm trying to make a get request to a web url using basic auth. But it failed with connection issues.

Note: It works when i use 'request' library instead  of 'got'

What I'm I missing here ?

```
const got = require('got');

(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await got( 
                      { 
                        url: 'https://httpbin.org/anything',
                        headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json'
                       //Authorization: 'Basic abcjghgh8****'
                      }
                    })
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('body:', res.body);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error:', error);
    }
})();
```

OUTPUT:

library

Answer (score 0):

When using `got()`, if you want the body, then you need to use `await got(...).json()` or `await got(...).text()` or whatever option is appropriate to your data type.  By default, the body has not yet been read (somewhat like the `fetch()` interface, but easier to use because you can just directly use the `.json()` method).

```
const got = require('got');

(async () => {
    try {
        const body = await got({
            url: 'some URL here',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Basic abcjghgh8****'
            }
        }).json(); // add .json() here
        console.log('body:', body);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error:', error);
    }
})();
```

And, `got().json()` resolves directly to the body.

You don't have to check the statusCode yourself because if it isn't a 2xx status, then it will reject the promise automatically.

Comment: i'm getting this after the change (async () => {
^.  TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is not a function

Comment: @itgeek - OK, I fixed that.  It appears like your code had an extra `}` in it as all I did was copy that from you.

Comment: }).json();                          // add .json() here
                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Comment: @itgeek - Well, I'm demonstrating how you solve this problem with `.json()` and since you didn't provide your actual URL, I didn't attempt to run the code.  I assume you can fix bracing syntax errors yourself, but I've edited my version one more time.  From here, you should be on your own.

Comment: thanks for your response . syntax isn't the problem here , i'm getting the first error that i share with you. TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is not a function

Comment: i got that example from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/got/v/5.0.0

Comment: @itgeek - Well, when I plug in an actual URL in the code currently in my answer, I can directly run that code in nodejs and it works for me.  Not sure what code you're running that generates that error so I don't know how to help you with that.  Isn't `.json()` the solution you were looking for to get the body of the response?

Comment: i just updated the question with some url

Comment: @itgeek - When I plug your URL into the code in my question, it works just fine for me.  It gets me a set of data.  I don't know what problem you are having with the code in my answer?  I don't know what else you need help with.